# Can you create an XYZ directory from geotiff

Tags: projection, gdal, geotiff

Can you create and XYZ directory structure with GDAL?  I have a bunch of geotiffs and I would like to re-project them with GDAL and create am XYZ directory structure.

Comment: Found this but that is TMS (almost XYZ).  http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html

Comment: What's a "XYZ directory structure"?

Comment: TMS vs XYZ: https://gist.github.com/tmcw/4954720

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to modify the gdal2tiles.py script with some help:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63024/gdal2tiles-maptiles-from-bsb-kap-are-switched